# Passing list of JSON objects to Controller via AJAX call

Tags: java, json, ajax, rest, classcastexception

Below is the data I am trying to pass

`var data=[{"TAG":"Taxes","REMARKS":"Enter Remarks"},{"TAG":"Taxes","REMARKS":"Enter Remarks"}];`

Ajax call to post data to controller:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "rest/url",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {                
        console.log(result);
    },
    error : function(xml, status, xhr) {            
        obj = (xml.responseText);
    }
});
```

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/url", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes="application/json",produces="application/json")
public @ResponseBody
LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList> getData(@RequestBody List<DataDTO> data,HttpServletRequest request1) {
System.out.println("Inside Controller :"+data.getClass())// getting Arraylist object
DataDTO dto1=data.get(0);// getting class cast exception
```

In the above code I am able to get data in controller in List format but when I am initialing object to a DTO class I am getting `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Post the code of `DataDTO` class too.

Comment: @SudhirOjha its a simple pojo class 

public class DataDTO{
String TAG;
String Remarks;

Getters and Setters
}

Answer (score 0):

Your `DataDTO` class should be like following because in `AJAX` you are using `TAG` and `REMARKS`. But in `DataDTO` class it is `TAG` and `Remarks`. So change your class like following:

```
public class DataDTO {
    private String TAG;
    private String REMARKS;
    //Getters and setters
}
```

Comment: I have consider cases but still I am getting this error. I am actually adding a row using below code in the json object.
$scope.data.unshift( {TAG:'Select Tag', REMARKS:'Enter New Remark'});

But when I am printing data in console log I am getting one more key 
[{"TAG":"Taxes","REMARKS":"Enter Remarks",,"$$hashKey":"object:280"}]

so to handle it in my DTO class I have made one more entry private String $$hashKey; with getter and setter

Comment: @RishiBeohar remove `$$hashKey` from your `DataDTO` class it is added by `angularjs`. Use `angular.toJson();` instead of `JSON.stringify()` in your ajax call.

Comment: Still getting this error "Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to"

Comment: is there any other way in which we can read List of JSON objects in controller  ? It will be very helpful if I can read the each json object seperately.